# Apache2 Virtual Host SSL Configuration

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost

I have a VirtualHost directive (virtualhost x.x.x.x:80 x.x.x.x:443) that listens for connections on both port 80 and port 443, how can I enable SSL only on port 443 within that directive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to create two separate VirtualHosts using separate `VirtualHost` directives, one for port 80 and one for port 443. Provide the SSL stuff only in your port 443 definition. You can `Include` the same configuration into both by splitting the common directives into a separate configuration file.